# Rust - idiomatic file search

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust. Could you share some tips for improving this code so it's more idiomatic and functional? I would prefer to stick to the standary library, and avoid unnecessary sorting or memory allocations.

```rust
fn first_file_in_dir(dir_path: &Path, extension: &str) -> Result<PathBuf, io::Error> {
    let mut matching_path = None;
    for entry in fs::read_dir(dir_path)? {
        let entry = entry?;
        if !entry.file_type()?.is_file() {
            continue;
        }
        let path = entry.path();
        if !path.extension().is_some_and(|x| x == extension) {
            continue;
        }
        if let Some(ref mut matching_path) = matching_path {
            if path < *matching_path {
                *matching_path = path;
            }
        } else {
            matching_path = Some(path);
        }
    }
    if let Some(matching_path) = matching_path {
        Ok(matching_path)
    } else {
        Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::NotFound,
                           format!("No *.{} file in {}", extension, dir_path.to_string_lossy())))
    }
}
```

The function returns the first file with a given extension inside a directory. Because the order of items from `fs::read_dir()` is platform dependent, it iterates over all files and picks the top one by name. Any I/O errors are propagated to the caller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code already looks fairly good. Some possible improvements:

## Use `cargo fmt`

... to format the code according to recommended style guidelines.

## Use `clippy`

... to lint your code. I recommend the additional options `-- -W clippy::pedantic -W clippy::nursery -W clippy::unwrap_used`.

## Use built-in functions

You use `Option::is_some_and()`. You may as well use `Option::ok_or_else()`.

## Subjective opinion

Matching `Some(ref mut)` is okay, but I prefer to match against `&mut option` instead.

## Suggested:

```rust
fn first_file_in_dir(dir_path: &Path, extension: &str) -> Result<PathBuf, io::Error> {
    let mut matching_path = None;

    for entry in fs::read_dir(dir_path)? {
        let entry = entry?;

        if !entry.file_type()?.is_file() {
            continue;
        }

        let path = entry.path();

        if !path.extension().is_some_and(|x| x == extension) {
            continue;
        }

        if let Some(matching_path) = &mut matching_path {
            if path < *matching_path {
                *matching_path = path;
            }
        } else {
            matching_path = Some(path);
        }
    }

    matching_path.ok_or_else(|| {
        io::Error::new(
            io::ErrorKind::NotFound,
            format!("No *.{} file in {}", extension, dir_path.to_string_lossy()),
        )
    })
}
```

## Alternative implementation

If you don't mind ignoring erroneous entries, you can even write the method as one expression:

```rust
pub fn first_file_in_dir(dir_path: &Path, extension: &str) -> Result<PathBuf, io::Error> {
    fs::read_dir(dir_path)?
        .filter_map(|result| {
            result.ok().and_then(|entry| {
                entry.file_type().ok().and_then(|file_type| {
                    if file_type.is_file()
                        && entry.path().extension().is_some_and(|x| x == extension)
                    {
                        Some(entry.path())
                    } else {
                        None
                    }
                })
            })
        })
        .reduce(|lhs, rhs| if lhs < rhs { lhs } else { rhs })
        .ok_or_else(|| {
            io::Error::new(
                io::ErrorKind::NotFound,
                format!("No *.{} file in {}", extension, dir_path.to_string_lossy()),
            )
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll enable the extra clippy lints, they are sure to come in handy. The alternative implementation is interesting. I managed to [simplify](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=31425024535aa4d55d175775646a0e42) it a bit. It would be real nice if Rust had a way to keep code so terse, while still propagating the errors.

Comment: That's neat. I didn't know about `Iterator::min()`.